# C++ retrieve numerical values in a line of string

Tags: c++, fstream

Here is the content of txt file that i've managed read.

```
X-axis=0-9
y-axis=0-9
location.txt
temp.txt
```

I'm not sure whether if its possible but after reading the contents of this txt file i'm trying to store just the x and y axis range into 2 variables so that i'll be able to use it for later functions. Any suggestion? And do i need to use vectors? Here is the code for reading of the file.

```
string configName;
ifstream inFile;

do {

    cout << "Please enter config filename: ";
    cin >> configName;

    inFile.open(configName);

    if (inFile.fail()){

        cerr << "Error finding file, please re-enter again." << endl;
        }
    } while (inFile.fail());

string content;
string tempStr;
while (getline(inFile, content)){

    if (content[0] && content[1] == '/') continue;
    cout << endl << content << endl;
```

Comment: Show the code you have so far.

Comment: Stick a line into an `std::stringstream` and split it with `std::getline()`. Parse an integer with `std::stoi()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you already have the whole contents of the .txt file in a single string somewhere. In that case, your next task should be to split the string. Personally, yes, I would recommend using vectors. Say you wanted to split that string by newlines. A function like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector> 

std::vector<std::string> split(std::string str)
{
    std::vector<std::string> ret;
    int cur_pos = 0;
    int next_delim = str.find("\n");

    while (next_delim != -1) {
        ret.push_back(str.substr(cur_pos, next_delim - cur_pos));
        cur_pos = next_delim + 1;
        next_delim = str.find("\n", cur_pos);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Will split an input string by newlines. From there, you can begin parsing the strings in that vector. They key functions you'll want to look at are `std::string`'s `substr()` and `find()` methods. A quick google search should get you to the relevant documentation, but here you are, just in case:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Now, say you have the string `"X-axis=0-9"` in `vec[0]`. Then, what you can do is do a `find` for `=` and then get the substrings before and after that index. The stuff before will be "X-axis" and the stuff after will be "0-9". This will allow you to figure that the "0-9" should be ascribed to whatever "X-axis" is. From there, I think you can figure it out, but I hope this gives you a good idea as to where to start!

Answer (score 0):

1. [`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) can be used to search for a character in a string;
2. [`std::string::substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) can be used to extract part of a string into another new sub-string;
3. [`std::atoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) can be used to convert a string into an integer.

So then, these three functions will allow you to do some processing on `content`, specifically: (1) search `content` for the start/stop delimiters of the first value (`=` and `-`) and the second value (`-` and [`string::npos`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos)), (2) extract them into temporary sub-strings, and then (3) convert the sub-strings to ints. Which is what you want.